# GDAL intersection returning NoneType in Python

Tags: gdal, geoprocessing, intersection

I have two shapefiles, one for landuse and one for subbasin. I want to find out how much landuse area is present within 3rd feature of subbasin shapefile. I am using following code.

```
fillu = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile').Open('landusen.shp')
LuLayers = fillu.GetLayer()

filsub = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile').Open('subs1.shp')
SubLayers = filsub.GetLayer()

LuGeom = [None]*len(LuLayers)
for i in range(len(LuLayers)):   # getting a list of geometries for landuse shapefile
    luf = LuLayers[i]
    luwkt = luf.GetGeometryRef() #geometry type
    luwkt = luwkt.ExportToWkt()
    lugeom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(luwkt)
    LuGeom[i] = lugeom

SubGeom = [None]*len(SubLayers)   # getting a list of geometries for subbasin shapefile
for i in range(len(SubLayers)):
    Subf = SubLayers[i]            # getting a feature from layer
    Subwkt = Subf.GetGeometryRef() #geometry type
    Subwkt = Subwkt.ExportToWkt()
    Subgeom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(Subwkt)
    SubGeom[i] = Subgeom


IntArea = 0
for i in range(len(SubLayers)):
    Int = LuGeom[2].Intersection(SubGeom[i])
    print(type(Int)
```

This is giving me following output

```
<class 'osgeo.ogr.Geometry'>
<class 'osgeo.ogr.Geometry'>
<class 'osgeo.ogr.Geometry'>
<type 'NoneType'>
<class 'osgeo.ogr.Geometry'>
<type 'NoneType'>
<class 'osgeo.ogr.Geometry'>
<class 'osgeo.ogr.Geometry'>
<class 'osgeo.ogr.Geometry'>
```

I am wondering why intersection of LuGeom[2] with SubGeom[3] and SubGeom[5] is of 'NoneType' I could calculate individual area of these three features and I can see graphically on QGIS that these three features do intersect.